# syslogd configuration problem

Tags: solaris, syslog

I'm having some problems with syslog on Solaris 10. It appears the configuration is not correct, and log messages are just piling up and never being written to /var/adm/messages.

Here's what's in /var/adm/messages:

```
Sep 10 03:10:17 air syslogd: Could not completely output pending messages while preparing re-configuration
Sep 10 03:10:17 air syslogd: discarded 1082 messages and restart configuration.
Sep 12 03:10:17 air syslogd: Could not completely output pending messages while preparing re-configuration
Sep 12 03:10:17 air syslogd: discarded 436 messages and restart configuration.
```

I issued this command:

```
$ logger -p daemon.notice "TESTING LOGGING"
```

and got the output in /var/adm/messages:

```
Sep 14 11:52:43 air gkwrcc: [ID 702911 daemon.notice] TESTING LOGGING
```

but no other messages seem to make it.

Here's my /etc/syslog.conf:

```
#ident  "@(#)syslog.conf        1.5     98/12/14 SMI"   /* SunOS 5.0 */
#
# Copyright (c) 1991-1998 by Sun Microsystems, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# syslog configuration file.
#
# This file is processed by m4 so be careful to quote (`') names
# that match m4 reserved words.  Also, within ifdef's, arguments
# containing commas must be quoted.
#
*.err;kern.notice;auth.notice                   /dev/sysmsg
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit        /var/adm/messages
auth.info       /var/adm/auth.log

*.alert;kern.err;daemon.err                     operator
*.alert                                         root           

*.emerg                                         *

# if a non-loghost machine chooses to have authentication messages
# sent to the loghost machine, un-comment out the following line:
#auth.notice                    ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/authlog, @loghost)

mail.debug                      ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/syslog, @loghost)

#
# non-loghost machines will use the following lines to cause "user"
# log messages to be logged locally.         
#                                            
ifdef(`LOGHOST', ,
user.err                                        /dev/sysmsg
user.err                                        /var/adm/messages
user.alert                                      `root, operator'
user.emerg                                      *
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have backticks in several places which should probably be single quotes.

Comment: Hmm...those appear to be in the default config file, but I'll comment them out and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Commenting out the backticks makes no difference. I am still seeing the same entries about discarding messages.